# To get id and its related all child id from same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get menu_id related all menu_id i.e, for menu_id 3 it should return

```
3,4,6,11
```

Following is my table:

[image: Table]

Comment: Hi justin, Welcome to SO.  This looks like a `Hierarchical/Dynamic select` query. You can not done with a simple select .

Comment: Hi Justin...Could you elaborate a bit more about your problem? on what basis you want the menu_ids from your table?

Comment: making a menu list. for menu_id 3 it is the main menu and related to all menu_id 3 its submenu. if i select 3 it should return 3,4,6,11.. my menu should contain like   3 define user-->4 user groups-->6 admin details-->11 mail system

Comment: That didnt help at all! If i got it right you get the menu parent from the row with id=3. This gives you 4. then you get the row with id=4, which gives you 6 and so on. right?

Comment: yes.want to execute in a single query..thanks in advance

Comment: as @SubinCPoonamgode mention, i also believe that this can not be done on a single select. maybe a sql function, or for sure using a programming language. I dont know any other way

Comment: Possible you look fof something like this hierarchical queries in mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query Unfortunatly, mysql doesn't support them yet but there are plently information on how to deal with it.

Comment: @justin if the level is fixed(a parent has max 7 hierarchical  child()), then it can be done in single query..

Answer (score 1):

I think this query work for you:

```
SELECT @id := (SELECT ms_menu_id FROM ms_menu WHERE ms_menu_parent = @id) 
   AS menu_id  FROM (SELECT @id := 3) vars STRAIGHT_JOIN ms_menu WHERE 
@id !=0  union all (select ms_menu_id from ms_menu where ms_menu_id=3) 
order by menu_id ASC limit 1, 18446744073709551615
```

results should be: 3,4,6,11

Comment: Interesting solution. Although only works if each parent only has one child.